# PHP, не работает exception

Tags: исключения, php, require_once

есть такая конструкция:

```
try
{
    require_once("Classes/".$class_name.".php");
} catch(Exception $e)
{
    Sys::Route("Error", "Notfound");
    exit;
}
```

но почему-то исключение не срабатывает, а выдаёт fatal error, с include_once то же самое, в чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> с include_once то же самое

Не так, чтобы то же самое. `require` выдает фатальную ошибку, а `include` — предупреждение.

`Fatal error` не ловится с помощью `try/catch`. Можете использовать `register_shutdown_function()`, но, как следует из названия — это конец.

Остальные ошибки можно поймать и "преобразовать" в исключение таким вот хитрым образом:

```
function handleError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext)
{
    // молчим, если ошибку подавили оператором @
    if (0 === error_reporting()) {
        return false;
    }

    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler('handleError');
```